# binding events on jquery created DOM elements

Tags: jquery

I like to create jquery elements in variables and place them where needed.

```
var $someElement = $("<span class='someclass'>something</span>").css("cursor", "pointer");
$("body").append($someElement)
```

for now everything is working. But if i try to bind a event to this element, the event does not get triggered:

```
var $someElement = $("<span class='someclass'>something</span>").css("cursor", "pointer").click(function(){ alert("yeah") });
$("body").append($someElement)
```

but if i append the element and the find the span by its class it works.

Why is this and how should i handle events on elements that are created but not yet apended?

Comment: Be sure to correct your mismatched tags. You're opening with a `<span>` and closing with a `</div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work just fine:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/HHNaF/ *(your code, copied and pasted)*

One alternative you have available to you is to [use `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to assign the handler:

```
$('span.someclass').live('click',function() {
   // do whatever
});
```

But still, your code should work. I'm guessing there's something else going on that is preventing the handler from triggering.

---

**EDIT:** Just noticed that your tags are mismatched. You start with `<span>` and end with `</div>`. Be sure to correct that. :o)

Comment: sorry for the example, in my script its right ;P but it does not work for some reason. I have to find out why. Thank you for your help

Comment: @meo - Perhaps a simple CSS issue, where some invisible element overlays the new one? Hard to say.

Comment: no because the "cursor : pointer" works. But i think its a JS problem, i have to integrade my script in a system that already uses a lot of uncommented JS :/

Answer (score 0):

Establish a delegated event handler for your elements with the `.delegate()` function.

```
$('#yourContainer').delegate('.someclass', 'click', function() { ... });
```

Then any of those "someclass" elements you drop inside "yourContainer" (which could be the `<body>` of course) will have its "click" events handled by that function.

Comment: Thanks @patrick dw!!  I need a cheat sheet in front of me for just about every API I use - you can imagine how painful it is to use Java all day :-)